# Where did H2 come from at pyruvate oxidation?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology

After pyruvate oxidation, H2 come out by pyruvate dehydrogenase. Does this mean H2 is from C3H4O3 (pyruvate)?

But then it makes no sense that numbers of pyruvate (C3H4O3) 's H and acetic acid (C2H4O2) 's H is same.

How can this happen if H is from pyruvate?

Comment: It's not clear what enzymatic reaction you mean, but since you mention acetic acid, I would guess it's the quinone-coupled pyruvate dehydrogenase (EC 1.2.5.1, also known as pyruvate oxidase). It would help if you write out the entire reaction.